# Merging Pandas DataFrames with the same column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, lets say:

```
Column with duplicates        value1       value2
        1                        5            0
        1                        0            9
```

And what I want

```
Column with duplicates        value1       value2
        1                        5            9
```

I cannot figure out how to get this to work. The closest I  got was using merge, but that left me with different suffixes.

Any ideas?

My real data looks like:

```
trial      Time       1    2      3      4
1         '0-100'     0    100    0      0
1         '0-100'     32    0     0      0
1         '100-200'   0     0    100     0
.
.
.
2         '0-100'     0    100    0      0
```

I want to keep the trials separate, and just merge the Times

Comment: What would you want to happen if there was a third line, `1 2 3`?  Or can that never happen?

Comment: That wouldn't happen. In my actual data, there are four numbers, so 

    `1 5 0 0 0`
    `1 0 9 0 0`

So the only thing that would happen would be the other two columns that are filled with zeros need to get filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and then aggregate:

```
>>> df
   Column with duplicates  value1  value2
0                       1       5       0
1                       1       0       9

[2 rows x 3 columns]
>>> df.groupby("Column with duplicates", as_index=False).sum()
   Column with duplicates  value1  value2
0                       1       5       9

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

On the OP's updated example:

```
>>> df
   trial       Time   1    2    3  4
0      1    '0-100'   0  100    0  0
1      1    '0-100'  32    0    0  0
2      1  '100-200'   0    0  100  0
3      2    '0-100'   0  100    0  0

[4 rows x 6 columns]
>>> df.groupby("trial", as_index=False).sum()
   trial   1    2    3  4
0      1  32  100  100  0
1      2   0  100    0  0

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: This ended up summing my Trials as well.

Comment: @NightHallow: no, it didn't, as the example you gave didn't *have* any trials.  And it shouldn't have summed it regardless (see my updated example).

Comment: The thing there is that I also want the "Time" to be kept separate.

I got it by doing
df.groupby("trial","Time").sum()

Comment: @NightHallow: some general advice-- we're happy to help, but you should give a minimal *but full* example right from the start.  It was only after a post, an edit, and three comments that you mentioned you wanted an axis that didn't even exist in your original example to be used as a key.  [I think it would need to be `df.groupby(["trial", "time"]).sum()`, BTW.]

Comment: I know, sorry. It was because I was testing with a smaller example, that turned out to be a bad one. The problem I have now is that since I have the time as '0-100' which is a string, it wont sort properly.